html link to another page not work, protocol fail
I'm trying to set a link to another page, using html.
It's really weird because it opens a new tab, but the page can't load. It says ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
If I click with the mouse in the webaddress in the browser and reload it with Enter, the page appears without any problems.
It's only when I open it from another side that I can't mature towards it.
does anybody knows the reason?
Thank you
tried to open it in the same tab, open it with javascript, open it in a pop up .
always the same problem

you may look here What's the net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR about? .. but you need further details to understand what's your actual scenario. Plus is not clear even what you said so far.. If I click with the mouse in the webaddress in the browser and reload it with Enter (why specifying those 2 steps instead of one?). It's only when I open it from another side .. you meant maybe site instead?

Sorry if I have expressed myself unclearly.
Let me explain it again.
When I type the destination URL into the web browser, the page loads without any problems.
When I call the target URL via link, it doesn't work.
<a href="target URL" target="_blank">test</a>
by chance I found out that the "not loaded" page is also reloaded correctly when I click in the web address and reconfirm the URL with "enter-key".

okay, i found out, the header shows "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"

and the dev-tools->network shows request blocked.
is it possible that the target site only works when i open it manually and not as a link.
it look's like the target site will be block the request, when i open it with a link

yes it looks like a cross origin policy issue. The target server will open the url when browsed from scratch by using directly the address bar, because the browser is not adding any referrer header to the request. But when you try to open the same url from an anchor link contained in  page coming from a different origin, the browser will add the referrer headers (the domain you are coming from) and the server doesn't allow to serve the page at those conditions. Those headers cannot be controlled from the browser for security reasons. But maybe there are tricks I'm not aware of

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

fix it with the rel tag. now it works.
